# Fetch posts by postId from firebase with swift 4

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

All I'm trying to achieve is to have the posts inside my radius append to the collection view. Currently I'm getting all the `postId` when the user enters the radius but nothing is being append to the collection view and I can't figure out why. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
var posts = [Post]()
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    let currentUserLocation = userLocation

    let circleQuery = geoFire?.query(at: currentUserLocation, withRadius: 100.0)
    _ = circleQuery?.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key, location) in

        guard let user = self.user else { return }
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(key)
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            var post = Post(user: user, dictionary: dictionaries)
            post.id = key

            self.posts.append(post)
            self.posts.sort(by: { (post1, post2) -> Bool in
                return post1.creationDate.compare(post2.creationDate) == .orderedDescending
            })

        }, withCancel: { (error) in
            print("There was an error getting the posts:", error)
        })

    })
}

    fileprivate func fetchPostUserIds() {
        Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            guard let userIdsDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            userIdsDictionary.forEach({ (key, value) in

                let uidKey = key
                self.geoFireRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(uidKey)
                self.geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: self.geoFireRef)

            })
        }) { (err) in
            print("Failed to get user Id", err)
        }
    }
```

[image: Firebase Database]

Comment: If you runt the code in a debugger, is the `self.posts.append(post)` being reached? If so, you're probably just forgetting to notify the view that it needs to repaint itself. Typically his would be something like `tableView.reloadData()`.

Comment: `self.posts.append(post)` isn't being executed. Do you think I might be accessing my database wrong? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: That sounds unexpected. Is that even the case when you put a breakpoint on it? Also, does the`print("There was an error getting the posts:", error)` get executed?

Comment: No `print("There was an error getting the posts:", error)` is not getting executed. When i placed a break point on `self.posts.append(post)` it didn't get reached. I have no idea why. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: OK. So if you put a breakpoint on `let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(key)` does *that* get hit. Note that at this point it's probably more efficient if you set a breakpoint on each line of your code, check where it gets, what the values of the various variables are, and then report all back in one go.

Comment: I added break point on line `circleQuery?.observe` and it returned a value of nil. I assume this isn't meant to happen. Do you know why? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: `observe` is supposed to return a handle, but I'm not sure if `_` changes that. Honestly, it's much more important if the first line inside that callback (`guard let user = self.user else { return }`) ever hits. If it doesn't then there are simply no objects that fall within the query's range.

Comment: The line `circleQuery?.observe` is returning a value of nil. But if I change                 `geoFireRef` and `geoFire` uidKey to the current users id instead it returns the values that I expected. Is there something wrong with how I'm setting it above? It seems that when I have to place `self.` in front of it then it just returns nil. @FrankvanPuffelen